# How to convert frontend javascript, including jQuery, with maximum compatibility using Babel?

Tags: jquery, babeljs

I'm using Babel-cli to try to make my javascript files compatible with older browsers.

Console:

```
npx babel $startPath --config-file $configFile --out-dir $endPathDefault --copy-files
```

Config:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env"],
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-member-expression-literals",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-property-literals",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-reserved-words"
  ]
}
```

But all my attempts result in error.

If I compile with the settings given above, my frontend returns:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

And in the settings that I managed to make work in modern browsers, I checked how it was running in old browsers, and it resulted in an error due to **Object.values**, **Object.entries** and due to the use of **Spread Operator**, where it returned "*is not a function* ".

Explaining the old browser I use for testing:

I have a webapp that runs my web system, if the browser supports ES6 it redirects to one version, otherwise it redirects to another version. And the old browser is a **Smart TV**, the app was programmed to run on Smart TVs.

I'm compiling Babel precisely for the old version only at the moment, and I've been trying for 5 days, without any success.

Anyone who had to do something similar or know how to do it, to help this poor guy?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at other answers, and finally got a result, but using Google Closure Compiler.

Here's my code using PHP to run the command line:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$startPath = 'START_PATH';

$endPathDefault = 'OUTPUT_PATH';

function processFiles($startPath, $endPath){
    
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($startPath));

    foreach($iterator as $file){
        
        $output = str_replace($startPath, $endPath, $file->getPathname());
        
        if($file->isFile() && strtolower(pathinfo($file->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) === 'js'){
            
            $command = "google-closure-compiler -O SIMPLE --js {$file->getPathname()} --js_output_file {$output} --language_in UNSTABLE --language_out ECMASCRIPT3 --warning_level QUIET --strict_mode_input false";

            shell_exec($command);
            
        }elseif($file->isFile()){
            
            copy($file->getPathname(), $output);
            
        }else{
            
            if(!file_exists($output)){
                mkdir($output, 0777, true);
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}

processFiles($startPath, $endPathDefault);
```